# How to SELECT one field form one table which is part of string contained in one field of another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

use PHP and MYsql. I have 2 tables like

- table 'tag': has field 'id' and 'tag' ('tag' is varchar)
- table 'entry': has fields 'tags' and other fields ('tags' is varchar that stores many words as tag, each word is separated by comma. Then I use function 'explode' to extract tags from string to store in array '$tags'. All tags from table 'entry' are stored in table 'tag'.)

What I want is to select all 'tag's from table 'tag' which are tags in the same string of 'tags' of table 'entry' that has a given tag (variable $tag). But no idea, I just try to SELECT tag from table 'entry' which string in 'tags' contains a specified tag (variable $tag).My current code is

```
$count=0;
$sql="SELECT tags FROM entry WHERE tag LIKE '%$tag%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){
    $tags1=explode(',',$data['tags']);
    for($loop=0; $loop<=count($tags1)-1; $loop++){
      if(!in_array($tags1[$loop], $tags2)){
        $count+=1; 
        $tags2[$count]=$tags1[$loop];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would normalizing your entry.tag field be entirely out of the question? i.e. add a third table, entries_tags(tag_id int, entry_id int)

Comment: thanks mootinator. How about add one more field in table 'tag'. Add 'entry_id' as the third field, but the problem is my existing data don't have the entry_id.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE entry ADD id int AUTO_INCREMENT` would add a unique id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulties you are having solving this problem all stem from the fact that you're storing a list of tags in a single column.

You really need to add an intersection table, to contain the data for the [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many) between tags and entries.  This is the proper way to design a relational database, and many SQL queries will become more efficient if you do that.

For example, to get all the tags from an entry that matches tag `$tag`:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT t1.tag FROM tag AS t1
INNER JOIN entries_tags AS e1 ON e1.tag = t1.id
INNER JOIN entries_tags AS e2 ON e2.entry = e1.entry
INNER JOIN tag AS t2 ON t2.id = e2.tag
WHERE t2.tag = ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute( array($tag) );

$data = $result->fetchAll();
$count = count($data);
```

I wrote a chapter to detail the practical problems caused by this design in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'm the beginner to PHP and Mysql. Your code is difficult for me.

Comment: @Bill I've got your book-SQL Antipatterns:Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming,and what I try to do in my question is called 'jaywalking'.So I created a new table named 'entry_tag' which has 3 fields 'id','entry_id','tag_id'(if one entry_id have many tag_id, I would store it in a different row).The existing table 'tag' is the same as previous(2 fields 'tag_id' and 'tag').I did try to use the code suggested above,it returned all tags from table 'tag' which have entry_id the same as a given tag in '$tag'.I observed that some of them were repeated.So how to get different tags in result.

Comment: You can try `SELECT DISTINCT t1.tag FROM ...`

Comment: Yeh!  Thank you so much Bill. ^^

Answer (score 2):

The super inefficient, SQL injection attack prone way of doing it as one statement would be:

```
$sql="SELECT tags FROM entry WHERE 1=1 ";
```

Then add each tag to the query before running it:

```
$sql.="AND tag LIKE '" . $tags1[$loop] . "' ";
```

If you want to match any tag instead of all tags replace `AND` with `OR`.

I'd really suggest normalizing the tags and looking into not building SQL queries that way though.